# Can I write multiple statements in an anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

Is it possible the write multiple statements in an anonymous function?

For example, I want to pass a function `f` as an argument to another function, which will attempt to call it multiple times in a loop, and I want `f` to do non-trivial work spread over multiple statements.

Clearly I can't write the following, since the second `disp` is not captured by the function -

```
>> f = @() disp('Hello'); disp('World')
World
```

I hoped I could use brackets to delimit the scope of the function, but while MATLAB accepts the syntax,

```
>> f = @() {disp('Hello'); disp('World')}

f = 

    @(){disp('Hello');disp('World')}
```

it doesn't like me calling the function -

```
>> f()
Error using disp
Too many output arguments.

Error in @(){disp('Hello');disp('World')}
```

Is there a solution, other than writing an inner function and passing that instead (which I am loathe to do, since debugging in an m-file that contains inner functions is difficult, since you can't create variables in the workspace).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no clean way to do this in MATLAB. There is a [great multi-part blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/) on abusing anonymous functions but it's far from easy to debug.

Comment: With regards to debugging nested functions in m-files, you can usually assign to `ans` *and* you can also use `assignin` to assign a variable to the base workspace to then inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that question @gnovice, not sure why I didn't find it!

Comment: @Suever thanks for the tips - should be useful in the future.